# Normalize two distributions having high standard deviation

Tags: normalization, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

What would be a proper way to normalize  two distributions with the following summary statistics, to make them comparable?

**Distribution 1**

```
count    10219.000000
mean        59.156180
std        103.880756
min          6.000000
25%         10.000000
50%         21.000000
75%         59.000000
max       2194.000000
```

**Distribution 2**

```
count     3213.000000
mean      3135.187675
std       2053.488213
min        101.000000
25%       1715.000000
50%       2684.000000
75%       3994.000000
max      24449.000000
```

Currently, I am scaling the mean of the first distribution to the mean of second distribution, but that essentially, this scales up the min and max of the first distribution above the second - which is not the desired result.

How can I perform a better normalization, perhaps taking the standard deviation as well into account?

Comment: How are you looking to compare the two distributions?

Comment: I have to put them in a single time series. So I am looking for some method which can make the min of both closer and also makes the max of both closer in range

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing why you want to normalize these distributions, let me assume you want to normalize them with respect to  a representative central tendency and dispersion, perhaps to compare their spread, or to compensate for a bias in measurement. Let us suppose that they could be globally unimodal, not too skewed. If not, normalization could be hopeless.

A larger standard deviation with respect to the mean, and a large gap between the upper quartile and the `max`:

`75%       3994.000000`;
`max      24449.000000`

may suggests potential outliers of the right side of the distributions. So with the figures you have, you could center them with respect to the median at `50%`, and divide by the interquartile range `75%` $-$ `25%`. Thus you will get two $0$-median and unit-interquartile range data. More fancy stuff could be performed afterward.

EDIT: following your comment "put them in a single time series", one interpretation is that you have two sets of measurements, from potentially uncalibrated sensors. I feel risky to merge them according to their extremal values (could be saturation, outliers). Instead, normalizing them wrt to a "majority" of samples could be sounder.

EDIT2: Keeping with the majority argument. As the first series is three times bigger, you may want to map the values of the 2nd series to the first one. Call $m_1$, $m_2$, $d_1$, $d_2$ their central tendencies and dispersions (e.g. median and interquartile range). Then, for any value $x_{\left(2\right)}$ in the second set, do $(x_{\left(2\right)}-m_2+m_1)\frac{d_1}{d_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to bring the min and max of the two distributions close to one or the other. It'd be modifying the distributions themselves and therefore throwing away the pattern or insights in the data.
If your question is how do I show them on a time series plot, there are a few options.

1. Use two y axes (y1 on the left and y2 on the right) and show both the distributions
2. Find the least common multiple of (min and  max) of each distribution and scale(as you say) the distributions separately to that value.